# How to remove the patched diff in cvs

Tags: diff, cvs

I have patched a diff file say new.Diff to the checked out code and done with my works in it.
Now is there any ways that I can get back the checked out code without the patched changes ie., removing all the changes included by new.Diff.

Thanks,
Preethi

Answer (score 1):

You can run:

```
cvs update -C
```

to discard all local changes applied and get a clean copy where on the original files revision (where you started)